# How to correctly synchronize a shared surface?

Tags: c++, directx

I am trying to share a direct3d9 surface between two processes. One process (let's call it A) writes to the surface, and the other (B) displays it on screen. Currently, process A does a StretchRect of its rendering surface to a shared surface, and then sets a flag in shared system memory to tell B that it's done. When B sees the flag, it then does a StretchRect of the shared surface to its own display surface. Process B then sets the flag again to tell A it is done.

It seems however that after the StretchRect on the shared surface returns, the texture has not necessarily finished copying, because sometimes Process B gets the previous picture, or sometimes even there is tearing (i.e. one half of picture N + one half of picture N + 1).

As I understand it, Direct3D is largely asynchronous under the hood, and does not ensure synchronisation between processes. I therefore need to ensure by myself that Process A has finished copying before displaying in process B, and vice-versa. Am I correct in my interpretation of the situation, and how would I achieve this? I am experimenting with LockRect() but I'm not sure if that's optimal or even guaranteed to work.

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Sharing_Resources):

> Shared cross-process surfaces provide no synchronization mechanism.
> Read/write changes to a shared surface may not reflect a referencing
> process's view of the surface when expected. To provide
> synchronization, use event queries or lock the texture.
>
> Only the
> process that initially creates a shared resource can lock it (any
> process that opens a reference to that shared resource cannot lock
> it).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm interested in an answer :)

Comment: IIRC, we figured out d3d9 didn't support this scenario and went with a solution that didn't involve sharing a surface on the graphics card. Things may have changed with d3d10 and above, though.

Answer (score 0):

your res sharing process is OK, I think. In dx9ex theres a flag in Present called D3DPRESENT_FORCEIMMEDIATE, can be used to force GPU render the resource, and then use the right picture later.